# Google Cast labels are not localised to device's language

Tags: swift, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I have implemented Google-Cast in my iOS application. It already casts content just fine but the whole UI is in English, even when my device language is set to something else. The library is supposed to have support for lots of languages but I cannot seem to make it work. I cannot access any of the components to change its text value.

I have tried to access the components through UI inspector but I don't think that the library is prepared to be modified like this.

Also tried to change UserDefaults to change the value for key "AppleLanguages".

If there is anything else I could try or you come up with ideas/solutions, please, feel free to help me out since I have ran out of ideas.

Comment: Research `i18n`. It will help you out. Also, I would advice to add some code of what you tried into your question. It will increase the chances of getting some help and reduce the chances of having your question flagged and removed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and we are working towards fixing this. We are targeting to release a fix in v4.4.2 release. Right now we do not have an ETA.

You can follow this bug for more updates: https://issuetracker.google.com/132135605